# x and y are changed in the picture. Where does it change in the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am upoading a picture and then the output picture is suddenly vertical flipped. I don't know where in the code it happens.

```
from scipy.interpolate.rbf import Rbf  # radial basis functions
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shrink import shrink2, shrink3

# Parameter
res = 5         # to add sequence of black points
smoo = -200       # to smooth rbf
eps = 2.8       # epsilon of rbf
shrinkEps = 4.

# import data
input = "testProbe3.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(input)   # load the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # convert it to grayscale
```

Until here i think nothing happens. maybe it have to happen somewhere here:

```
#Reduce pixels
shrinked = shrink3(gray, int(gray.shape[0]/3), int(gray.shape[1]/3))
```

Is it right that first y and then x?

```
# # Add white Points
y, x = np.where(shrinked >= 0)

# Set z values to summed values
z=[]
```

here, too: first loop over y (the rows) and then over x (the columns), right?

```
for y1 in range(0, shrinked.shape[0]):
    for x1 in range(0, shrinked.shape[1]):
        z = np.append(z, shrinked.item(y1,x1))
```

Then plotting a meshgrid normal with xx and yy ?

```
# meshgrid
x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
ti = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, (x_max-x_min+1)*3)
tii = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, (y_max+y_min+1)*3)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ti, tii)
```

and rbf interpolation normal with x, y, z?

```
# rbf interpolation
rbf = Rbf(x, y, z, function='gaussian', epsilon=eps/shrinkEps, smooth=smoo)
zz = rbf(xx, yy)
jet = cm = plt.get_cmap('jet')
plt.pcolor(xx, yy, zz, cmap=jet)
plt.colorbar()
```

I think here couldn't be the mistake:

```
# Plotting the original points.
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.title('epsilon = %e/%s, smooth=%s, res=%r, Auflösung 1x gedrittelt, 1x halbiert, testProbe3.jpg'%(eps, shrinkEps, smoo, res))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(9, 7)

plt.show()
```

Here's my module shrink, that I have defined:

```
def shrink3(data, rows, cols):
    if data.shape[0] % 3:                       # Wenn Zeilen nicht durch 3 teilbar
        if (data.shape[0] - 1) % 3 == 0:        # dann reduziere um 1
            data = data[0:data.shape[0] - 1, :]
        elif (data.shape[0] - 2) % 3 == 0:      # sonst reduziere um 2
            data = data[0:data.shape[0] - 2, :]
    if data.shape[1] % 3:                       # Wenn Spalten nicht durch 3 teilbar
        if (data.shape[1] - 1) % 3 == 0:        # dann reduziere um 1
            data = data[:, 0:data.shape[1] - 1]
        elif (data.shape[1] - 2) % 3 == 0:      # sonst reduziere um 2
            data = data[:, 0:data.shape[1] - 2]
    return data.reshape(rows, int(data.shape[0]/rows), cols, int(data.shape[1]/cols)).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can try showing the image in different places in your code. I would start by showing the image after `shrinked` since I'm not sure what that function does.

Comment: @Christoffer Thank you for your answer. I added the shrink funktion to my description of the code. Plotting `shrinked` isn't helping me, because the image is not meaningful.

Comment: That's because `imread` always reads the image with [the origin on the upper left corner](http://answers.opencv.org/question/35111/origin-pixel-in-the-image-coordinate-system-in-opencv/)?

Comment: @jadelord. Yes I think this is the problem. I inverted y and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like `plt.pcolor` inverted my array y. So used the following code to correct it:

```
# inverse y
y = y[::-1]
```

Now my image looks right.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, look at the lines marked with `!!!!`:

```
#Reduce pixels
shrinked = shrink3(gray, int(gray.shape[0]/3), int(gray.shape[1]/3))
# # Add white Points
!!!! y, x = np.where(shrinked >= 0)

# Set z values to summed values
z=[]
for y1 in range(0, shrinked.shape[0]):
    for x1 in range(0, shrinked.shape[1]):
        z = np.append(z, shrinked.item(y1,x1))
# meshgrid
x_min, x_max = x.min() - 1, x.max() + 1
y_min, y_max = y.min() - 1, y.max() + 1
ti = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, (x_max-x_min+1)*3)
tii = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, (y_max+y_min+1)*3)
!!!! xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ti, tii)

# rbf interpolation
rbf = Rbf(x, y, z, function='gaussian', epsilon=eps/shrinkEps, smooth=smoo)
zz = rbf(xx, yy)
jet = cm = plt.get_cmap('jet')
plt.pcolor(xx, yy, zz, cmap=jet)
plt.colorbar()
```

You switch the `x` and `y`. Maybe you can do:

```
yy, xx = np.meshgrid(tii, ti)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BrunoGL. I already tried it, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

A totally guess. Anything wrong here?

```
rbf = Rbf(x, y, z, function='gaussian', epsilon=eps/shrinkEps, smooth=smoo)
```

Will it help to switch `x` and `y`

```
rbf = Rbf(y, x, z, function='gaussian', epsilon=eps/shrinkEps, smooth=smoo)
```

Comment: No, then the picture turns 90 degrees